# How to sum specific rows in iReport with query?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to create a summary table using iReport.  My dataset is returning a list of purchases made and prices.  Something like

`Milk, $1.23`

`Chicken, $5.45`

`Milk, $1.44`

and so on.  I want my table to be able to breakdown my item by product.  I want a table with columns:

- # of times product was purchased (#rows where product milk),
- total dollar amount spent on the product (sum of prices where product is milk),
- and average price of product (column 2 divided by column 1).

How can I do this?  I have been playing around with variables and I can get a total sum of all prices, but I don't know how to do this with a subset of the data using a more complex query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite easy. You can create group on **product** field and two variables on this group: for counting result sum and average sum. With help of built-in variable you can calculate and display the number of elements in this group.

This is working sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="group_average2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="product" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <sortField name="product"/>
    <variable name="totalSum" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="productGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="averageSum" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="productGroup" calculation="Average">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="productGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="122" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
                    <reportElement x="244" y="0" width="122" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{totalSum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="122" y="0" width="122" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{productGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
                    <reportElement x="366" y="0" width="149" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{averageSum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="19">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="-1" width="122" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Product]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="122" y="-1" width="122" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Number of orders]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="244" y="-1" width="122" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total sum]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="366" y="-1" width="149" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Average sum of order]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

This sample takes CSV file as datasource. You can edit query - for getting data with SQL query.

The report design in *iReport* is:

[image: The report design]

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image: The result in iReport]

You should read this article about [using variables in *JasperReports*](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_using_variables.html) and this post about [using groups in *JasperReports*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups).

Please **remember** that you should sort the data before group using.
The quote from the post about grouping and sorting from the *jasperforge.org*:

`In order to get an accurate data representation, the data in the data source should be already ordered according to the group expressions used in the report. One can either perform data sorting through the report query, or use the <sortField/> element.`

Comment: Thank you!  The trick that I was missing was the group band.  The part about iReport I keep struggling with is the bands.  The same variable will display different results depending on what band it goes in.  Why does it matter if the data is sorted or not?

Comment: As an addendum to my original problem... Is there a way to use a multiplier to my total sum?  I have an additional column, state, indicating the state it was purchased in.  I have a STATE_SALES_TAX table that I want to query for each record.  If buy my milk in NJ, the sales tax is 1.06.  I buy another gallon in NY and it is 1.08.  Is there a way that I can sum up the total spent on milk using this multiplier from another table?  Total spent on milk = sum (eachMilkPx * salesTax(statePurchased))

Comment: Yes, you can create any variable's expression you need.